# List , cast and IEnumerable issues

Tags: .net, vb.net

what i'm trying to do with this code is to select data information from my data base and  put the results query   in a list  , then add the results to a new list that i'm going to use  later... But that gives me  the error:

---

> unable to  cast object of type `WhereSelectListIterator<
>       jTableSampleDatabaseLayer.Hik.JTable.Models.Concour,
>       VB$AnonymousType_0<string, int?, int?, DateTime, int, int, string, int?>>` to type `IEnumerable<jTableSampleDatabaseLayer.Hik.JTable.Models.Concour>`

---

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports jTableSampleDatabaseLayer.Hik.JTable.Models

Namespace Hik.JTable.Repositories.Memory

    Public Class MemoryData
        Dim x As jTableSampleDatabaseLayer.totofootEntities = New jTableSampleDatabaseLayer.totofootEntities
        Public Function ListeConcours() As MemoryDataSource
            Dim dataSource = New MemoryDataSource()
            Dim liste As List(Of Concour) = x.Concours.ToList()
            Dim ccrs = From concours In liste Select concours.numero_concours, concours.numero_type, concours.numero_nature, concours.date_de_sortie, concours.nbre_matchs, concours.nbre_rangs, concours.titre_concours, concours.numero_etape

            dataSource.Concours.AddRange(ccrs)
            Return dataSource
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

As you can see, I may really have no idea how to work this out . Does anyone have any insight on what I may be doing wrong and how I can resolve it?

this is the class memorydatasource :

```
`Imports System.Collections.Generic
```

Imports jTableSampleDatabaseLayer.Hik.JTable.Models

Namespace Hik.JTable.Repositories.Memory

```
Public Class MemoryDataSource

    Public Property Types As List(Of Type)
    Public Property Concours As List(Of Concour)
    Public Property Natures As List(Of Nature)
    Public Property Etapes As List(Of Etape)

    Public Sub New()

        Types = New List(Of Type)()
        Natures = New List(Of Nature)()
        Etapes = New List(Of Etape)()
        Concours = New List(Of Concour)()

    End Sub
End Class
```

End Namespace

`

Comment: what is memorydatasource? Is that your custom class ?

Comment: I took the liberty of reformatting the type declarations in the error message from the "standard" syntax into the C# syntax for generics, and using shorter type names, this should honestly be more readable to everyone. (It would be better to use VB.NET syntax for them in this question but I'm not familiar with VB.NET enough.)

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of the LINQ expression after `Dim ccrs = ...`? If `dataSource.Concours` is (I'm guessing) a `List<Concour>`, and `liste` is a `List<Concour>`, why not just use `dataSource.Concours.AddRange(ccrs)`.

Comment: ok thnks millimoose ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to put the select results into a new object of type **Councur**. Then you will be able to add the query to the **Councours** list:

```
' pseudo code!!!
Dim ccrs = From concours In liste 
            Select new Councur 
                Num = concours.numero_concours
                Typ = concours.numero_type, 
                Nat = concours.numero_nature, 
                Dat = concours.date_de_sortie, 
                Mat = concours.nbre_matchs, 
                Ran = concours.nbre_rangs, 
                Con = concours.titre_concours, 
                Eta = concours.numero_etape
```

Answer (score 0):

The query

```
From concours In liste
Select concours.numero_concours, 
       concours.numero_type, 
       concours.numero_nature, 
       concours.date_de_sortie, 
       concours.nbre_matchs, 
       concours.nbre_rangs, 
       concours.titre_concours, 
       concours.numero_etape
```

returns values that have an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) (because you specified more than one value to select) instead of the type of values expected by `dataSource.Concours.AddRange`, which appears to be `Concour`.

If you avoid the query altogether, you should be adding the right kind of thing. I'm not sure if this code does what you want, but it's more likely to compile:

```
Dim x As jTableSampleDatabaseLayer.totofootEntities = New jTableSampleDatabaseLayer.totofootEntities
Public Function ListeConcours() As MemoryDataSource
    Dim dataSource = New MemoryDataSource()
    Dim liste As List(Of Concour) = x.Concours.ToList()

    dataSource.Concours.AddRange(liste)
    Return dataSource
End Function
```

I believe the above code makes an in-memory copy of the concours and returns it, exposed as a MemoryDataSource. It may be possible to avoid the `ToList`, depending on what the semantics of AddRange are.

Comment: thank you Strilanc  that solves the problem ... but when i use  this without the query the results from the DB sames to return nothing  although this way actually works with c# language :p any suggestions please !!!!